# I need to include file in array

Tags: php

I tried to include the php file in array like that but it is not working
username.php file is : `"mohammed", "ahmed", "hafian", "gimmy", "osama"`
and the main file is : `$usernames = array(include 'usernames.php');`

Answer (score 1):

In `usernames.php` do:

```
<?php
return ["mohammed", "ahmed", "hafian", "gimmy", "osama"];
```

In `foo.php` do:

`$usernames = include 'usernames.php';`

RTM: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-145

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open and read the file, you can't just include and expect it to parse the file and store into your array.  Also, can you make usernames.php a text file and not PHP code? You don't want to be parsing PHP code. I think you'll need to approach it like this:

```
`<?php
  $fn = fopen("usernames.txt","r");

  while(! feof($fn))  {
     $result = fgets($fn);
     # parse line and append to array
  }

  fclose($fn);
?>`
```